# Is it possible to make dynamic range in angular daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-daterangepicker

In usual case scenario:

```
vm.datePickerRangeOptions = {
  ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()]
  }
};
```

would be sufficient. This way I have defined range with todays start and end date. The problem occurs once the time passes: when page is not refreshed range 'Today' still points to day when page was rendered.

What I tried so far was adding some event handler:

```
vm.datePickerRangeOptions = {
  ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()]
  },
  eventHandlers: {
    'show.daterangepicker': a
  },
};

function a() {
   vm.datePickerRangeOptions.ranges = {
     'Today': [moment(), moment()]
  };
}
```

but once date picker was shown it was closed immediately.

Second approach was to set `vm.dateRangePickerOptions` as a function and set to `option` on input view. Js:

```
vm.dateRangePickerOptions = function() {
  return {
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()]
    }
  }
}
```

and template:

```
<input date-range-picker name="daterange" ng-model="vm.datePicker.date"
       options="vm.datePickerRangeOptions()">
```

In this case I receive an error from moment.js:

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular daterangepikcer](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) is a wrapper for [bootstrap daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) and according to its creator it is not possible (issues: [#1137](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/1137), [#1516](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/1516)).

To update date range values one can set them in some time interval. Eg:

```
function updateRanges() {
  vm.datePickerRangeOptions.ranges = {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
  }

  var now = moment();
  var startOfTomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day');
  $timeout(updateRanges, startOfTomorrow.diff(now));
}
```

Side note: if you want to update date ranges and you have set `maxDate`, don't forget to update it also in time interval.